# How to create a mapping table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables as below

`CITY_A`

| ID | CODE | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 90 | PARIS |
| 002 | 90 | PARIS |
| 003 | 85 | PARIS |
| 004 | 60 | SYDNEY |
| 005 | 75 | SYDNEY |
| 006 | 75 | SYDNEY |

`CITY_B`

| ID | CODE | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | IN | PA |
| 002 | OUT | PA |
| 003 | OUT | PA |
| 004 | IN | SYD |
| 005 | OUT | SYD |
| 006 | IN | SYD |

The content is same in both tables but the representation is different. I have 2 mapping here for `CITY` column and `CODE` column.

Mapping for `CITY_A`

| CODE | CITY | MEANING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | PARIS | ACTIVE |
| 85 | PARIS | NOT_ACTIVE |
| 60 | SYDNEY | ACTIVE |
| 75 | SYDNEY | NOT_ACTIVE |

Mapping for `CITY_B`

| CODE | CITY | MEANING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IN | PA | ACTIVE |
| OUT | PA | NOT_ACTIVE |
| IN | SYD | ACTIVE |
| OUT | SYD | NOT_ACTIVE |

Now i have to compare both tables based on the mapping and find the mismatches. So my expected output is

| ID | CITY | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | PARIS | MATCH |
| 002 | PARIS | MISMATCH |
| 003 | PARIS | MATCH |
| 004 | SYDNEY | MATCH |
| 005 | SYDNEY | MATCH |
| 006 | SYDNEY | MISMATCH |

Currently I'm using `CASE` with Temp table. It is too big.

```
SELECT A.ID , CASE WHEN A.CODE = 90 AND A.CITY = 'PARIS' THEN 'ACTIVE' 
                   WHEN A.CODE = 85 AND A.CITY = 'PARIS' THEN 'NOT_ACTIVE' 
               -- FOR OTHER CITIES
               END AS A.CODE_MEANING,
               CITY
INTO #TEMP_CITY_A              
FROM CITY_A A

SELECT B.ID,CASE WHEN B.CODE = 'IN'  AND B.CITY='PA' THEN 'ACTIVE'
                   WHEN B.CODE = 'OUT'  AND B.CITY='PA' THEN 'NOT_ACTIVE' 
              -- FOR OTHER CITIES
            END AS B.CODE_MEANING,
            CASE WHEN B.CITY = 'PA' THEN 'PARIS' 
                 WHEN B.CITY = 'SYD' THEN 'SYDNEY'
            END AS CITY
 INTO #TEMP_CITY_B              
 FROM CITY_B B

SELECT A.ID ,A.CITY, CASE WHEN A.CODE_MEANING!=B.CODE_MEANING THEN 'MISMATCH' ELSE 'MATCH' END AS RESULT
FROM #TEMP_CITY_A A
JOIN #TEMP_CITY_B B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.CITY = B.CITY
```

Which is the most efficient way?

Comment: Could you please give us your tables and data as a fiddle <db-fiddle.uk>. It's a big ask to get others to do all that work on your behalf - also, it eliminates errors and/or duplication of effort for those who are trying to help you!

Comment: [duplicate on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822562/efficient-way-for-creating-mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create intermediate derived tables of your main and mapping tables and then join these to compare and use a `CASE` statement to check the matching rows.

```
CREATE TABLE #MAP_CITY_A (CODE TINYINT, CITY VARCHAR(10), MEANING VARCHAR(10))
INSERT #MAP_CITY_A (CODE,CITY,MEANING)
VALUES (90, 'Paris', 'Active'),(85, 'Paris', 'Not_Active'),(60, 'Sydney', 'Active'),(75, 'Sydney', 'Not_Active')

CREATE TABLE #MAP_CITY_B (CODE VARCHAR(3), CITY VARCHAR(10), MEANING VARCHAR(10))
INSERT #MAP_CITY_B (CODE,CITY,MEANING)
VALUES ('IN', 'PA', 'Active'),('OUT', 'PA', 'Not_Active'),('IN', 'SY', 'Active'),('OUT', 'SY', 'Not_Active')


SELECT a.ID,
       a.CITY,
       CASE 
          WHEN a.MEANING = b.MEANING THEN 'MATCH'
          ELSE 'MISMATCH'
       END as RESULT
FROM
(
    SELECT CITY_A.ID, CITY_A.CITY, #MAP_CITY_A.MEANING 
    FROM CITY_A 
    JOIN #MAP_CITY_A ON CITY_A.CODE = #MAP_CITY_A.CODE
         AND CITY_A.CITY = #MAP_CITY_A.CITY
) a
JOIN 
(
    SELECT CITY_B.ID, #MAP_CITY_B.MEANING 
    FROM CITY_B 
    JOIN #MAP_CITY_B ON CITY_B.CODE = #MAP_CITY_B.CODE
         AND CITY_B.CITY = #MAP_CITY_B.CITY
) b  
ON a.ID = b.ID
ORDER BY a.ID
```